# Bug when i try to start azure emulator - many node processes have been started

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2013, iis-express, azure-compute-emulator

Sometimes then i start my site on `Azure emulator` & `IIS express` i see the following :
[image]

That processes are stored in `{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\ouwrt4m1.qjw\Resources\nodej`

The site continue working but i'm losing 11 gb of RAM. Also, my computer is working slowly after it. I can solve that problem by restarting the computer.

Comment: Are you testing the Azure Cloud Service on local with Azure Emulator? And are you hosting your node application on Web Role or Worker Role?

Comment: @juvchan Right now `Compute emulator` & `Storage emulator` are started, i don't remember that we use node in our project.

Comment: When i stopped Azure emulator node processes were still worked

Comment: @DotNetGoose, Could you please share your VS version and PC environment?

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013 update 5

Comment: @DotNetGoose, I will try to reproduce it on my side. Any updates, I will reply you ASAP.

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT that behaviour is occured not immediately, need to work some time to get it. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I find a workaround:
i run a `cmd` file with admin access rights like the following:

```
taskkill /f /im node.exe
```